# How to reset CORS Max Age in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, cors, azure-blob-storage

I enabled CORS in my Azure blob storage.
But when I first enable the CORS, I set max-age as 86400.
So After one day, I couldn't connect to Azure blob storage as it was expired.

How can I reset that CORS setting?
And also can I set that CORS max-age as permanent?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `I couldn't connect to Azure blob storage as it was expired` - This tells me that you are using a SAS URL to connect to blob storage. If that's the case, then you would need to regenerate a new SAS URL. CORS max-age setting is related to caching of CORS rules by user agent (browser, for example) and should not have any impact on accessing the blob.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are correct. I also just found the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Thanks to @[Gaurav Mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67088308/azure-storage-blob-cors-errors) for leading into right direction and making it as a solution to help others also.
- Yes i do agree with @ Gaurav Mantri that `I couldn't connect to Azure blob storage as it was expired` - This indicates that you are using a SAS URL to connect to blob storage. If that's the case, then you would need to regenerate a new SAS URL.
- CORS max-age setting is related to caching of [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services) rules by user agent (browser, for example) and should not have any impact on accessing the blob
- From my end I created a blob storage and under settings added cores as shown in below image.

Here i am taking Blob service under this,

**Allowed method**s = GET,POST,PUT

**Allowed headers** = x-ms-blob-type,content-type

**Exposed headers** = x-ms-blob-type

**Max age** = 300
[image]
The Max age value must not be empty. The value must be at **least 0**. The value must be **at most 2147483647**.

> How can I reset that CORS setting? And also can I set that CORS
> max-age as permanent?

If you want to edit these core settings, you can simply select created one and you can edit all those allowed properties and max age.

- Yes you can set to max age as permanent but please note that setting the max-age value to a very large number may not be the best security practice as it may expose your storage account to potential security risks.